# Angularfire2 firestore snapshotChanges not retriving data unless the app is reloaded after login

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

I'm trying to retrieve data from firestore once user login in an Ionic 3 App. The snapshotChanges returns null on first login. But once I restart the app, it retrieves the data. What might be the problem?

```
getMsg(chatRoomName, privateGroupChatroomName, sortBy, count = 10) {
    this.todosCollection = this.afs.collection('chat').doc(chatRoomName)
        .collection<chatMsg>(privateGroupChatroomName, ref => ref.orderBy(sortBy, 'desc').limit(count))
    return this.chatCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(map(msg => {
        return msg.map(col => {
            const data = col.payload.doc.data();
            const id = col.payload.doc.id;
            const doc = col.payload.doc;
            return { id, ...data, doc };
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: Found the solution.

I did 
this.angularFS.firestore.disableNetwork(); on logout but didn't added 

this.angularFS.firestore.enableNetwork(); on Login. Once I added this line of code inside firebase.auth, Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Globals.userDetails.email, 'KafeTEENgoogleFirebasePwd').then(cred => {
              this.angularFireStore.firestore.enableNetwork();
              console.log('Firebase log in');
            }
```

this.angularFireStore.firestore.enableNetwork(); - this line of code solved the issue.